# JDK8: When does old generation object get marked as unreachable?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

I am troubleshooting a Java service where it occasionally gets a big increase of old generation utilization to 80%+ and then drops back down.

I was able to run a jmap against the process in the host. While doing so, inadvertently triggered a full GC on the process. Then suddenly, the old generation utilization drops to 20%.

This seems to suggest that there's a lot of unreachable objects in the old generation space that only get cleaned up during a full gc.

This makes me wonder when the JVM decides to check if old generation objects are unreachable. Is this a background process? Or is it done only during a major GC? Or through some other mechanisms? I tried getting this information from the Oracle documentations (E.g. https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) but I don't see it being described too precisely. It does mention the marking is done during a GC but did not say if that's exclusively the case.

I would appreciate it if one or more of you can advise on this topic or point me to an page that documents this.

Thanks in advance!

Update:

- Parallel Collector is used
- No, I am not saying full GC is an error. Rather, I am wondering when old generation objects are marked as reachable/unreachable. One of the third party metrics I am using suggests in its documentation that it measures memory utilization by "reachable" objects in old generation space and so I wonder when the JVM actually "knows" when the objects are not reachable anymore (e.g. only during the full GC?).

Comment: Is your question : when a Full GC is triggered? Also, are you using G1?

Comment: I am using Parallel Collector

Answer (score 2):

(It started out as a comment and then grew)
First off, that your old gen grows to 80% and then drops after a full gc does in no way indicate that your application is broken or that you have a problem with it. Only start fiddling around with gc if you have performance problems that can be attributed to gc and also measure! Save gc logs from before and compare them with after! 
your questions then!

An object cannot be marked as `unreachable` because it is by definition unreachable. 
When the old gen is gc:ed, all live (reachable) objects are `marked`. Then, depending on the collector, the (old gen) heap is either scanned for live objects that will be compacted or in the case of G1, the live objects are copied to another region. All objects that are not marked as live will simply be ignored and overwritten as needed.
As per background process, this depends on the collector. The parallell collector will not run in the background, instead it will pause the execution of your app while for instance CMS or G1 will run in the background (as will Shenandoah & Z).


I missed your heading that it was JDK8. Unless you specifically state otherwise, the default collector is the parallell collector mentioned above. Your app will run on all available cpu-resources until it's time for a full gc (the only interesting one for this discussion). It will then pause the the app and use all cpu:s for doing a full gc.
If this is not what you want, switch over to CMS which will perform gc almost concurrently. Note however that using CMS pays a price in cpu availability for your app. Since CMS runs concurrently it will need cpu, that cpu will not be available for you app to do work.

Comment: Just wondering why you are suggesting a deprecated and removed collector?

Comment: JDK8 (says so in the title) ? I could recommend upgrading to versions above but that seemed out of scope.
For me, really, the important part seemed to be that OP seemed to regard a full gc as an error and I wanted to adress that.

Comment: so you recommend the deprecated CMS because the OP is on jdk8? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: Really? My experience with jdk8, G1 and CMS leads me to recommend CMS in preference to G1 but that's me. But, if you read my first paragraph I specifically state that the GC pauses that OP reports are not necessarily indications of a misbehaving application and that's the important thing. 
Apart from that, of course OP should upgrade to something better but that's not what's in the post.

Comment: Yeah upgrading CDK version is not in scope of my question. I updated my original comment with some clarification. I am mostly interested in knowing if the marking of the old generation objects only occurs during a major GC

Comment: @user1836155 yes. only when old generation is scanned (mark phase), it is known what is live and dead.

Comment: @Erik I guess it depends on the application, but so far, across around 1000 micro-services (until  1 year back when we upgraded to Shenandoah everywhere), we used `G1`. If I had to pick one single reason, I would choose : String deduplication.